# Seeking 2D version of approxfun()

Tags: r, interpolation

I am seeking in R a 2D version of `stats::approxfun()` that can generate an interpolation *function* f(x,y) from an (x,y,z) dataset. I have not found one in the package `akima` or elsewhere.

Comment: Searching SO with "r 2d interpolation" provides many examples.

Comment: @42- many examples of `function`s being generated, or many examples of just the interpolation itself? A very quick search didn't turn up too many obvious examples for me.

Comment: If you have a procedure that let's you construct a prediction between your points, how is that not a "function"? Just wrapping `predict` around a model object (or a non-parametric operation such as `loess`) in a `function` body ought to satisfy this request, unless of course you have expectations that remain unarticulated.

Comment: I believe the OP indeed has additional expectations that, though unarticulated, are quite obvious. I have tried to make those expectations more explicit in my bounty.

Comment: In the **cooltools** package there is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to readapt the `interp.surface` function from the R package [`fields`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fields/index.html). An example readapted from the `?interp.surface`:

Load package

```r
library(fields)
#> Warning: package 'fields' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> Loading required package: spam
#> Warning: package 'spam' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> Loading required package: dotCall64
#> Warning: package 'dotCall64' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> Loading required package: grid
#> Spam version 2.7-0 (2021-06-25) is loaded.
#> Type 'help( Spam)' or 'demo( spam)' for a short introduction 
#> and overview of this package.
#> Help for individual functions is also obtained by adding the
#> suffix '.spam' to the function name, e.g. 'help( chol.spam)'.
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'spam'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     backsolve, forwardsolve
#> Loading required package: viridis
#> Loading required package: viridisLite
#> 
#> Try help(fields) to get started.
```

Load data

```r
data(lennon)
obj <- list(x = 1:20, y = 1:20, z = lennon[201:220, 201:220])
```

Define the approximating function

```r
approxfun_2d <- function(x, y) {
  interp.surface(obj, cbind(x, y))
}
```

Test it

```r
set.seed(1)
approxfun_2d(x = runif(1, min = 1, max = 20), y = runif(1, min = 1, max = 20))
#> [1] 33.34148
```

Plot original data

```r
image.plot(obj)
```

[image]

Compute interpolations

```r
x_interp <- runif(2e2, 1, 20)
y_interp <- runif(2e2, 1, 20)
z_interp <- approxfun_2d(x_interp, y_interp)
```

Plot approximation

```r
quilt.plot(x_interp, y_interp, z_interp)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This is not 100% equal to a 2D version of `approxfun`, but it may be good enough for most purposes.

Comment: It does not return a function unless manually added, which is not ideal. This package also requires a matrix Z input, which is an unnecessary constraint.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

If you want to return a function, you can define

```
library(pracma)
x <- linspace(-1, 1, 11)
y <- linspace(-1, 1, 11)
mgrid <- meshgrid(x, y)
Z <- mgrid$X^2 + mgrid$Y^2
xp <- yp <- linspace(-1, 1, 101)

approxfun2 <- function(x, y, Z, method = "linear") {
  function(xp, yp) interp2(x, y, Z, xp, yp, method)
}

f <- approxfun2(x, y, Z)
```

and you will see

```
> is.function(f)
[1] TRUE

> f(xp, yp)
  [1] 2.000 1.928 1.856 1.784 1.712 1.640 1.568 1.496 1.424 1.352 1.280 1.224
 [13] 1.168 1.112 1.056 1.000 0.944 0.888 0.832 0.776 0.720 0.680 0.640 0.600
 [25] 0.560 0.520 0.480 0.440 0.400 0.360 0.320 0.296 0.272 0.248 0.224 0.200
 [37] 0.176 0.152 0.128 0.104 0.080 0.072 0.064 0.056 0.048 0.040 0.032 0.024
 [49] 0.016 0.008 0.000 0.008 0.016 0.024 0.032 0.040 0.048 0.056 0.064 0.072
 [61] 0.080 0.104 0.128 0.152 0.176 0.200 0.224 0.248 0.272 0.296 0.320 0.360
 [73] 0.400 0.440 0.480 0.520 0.560 0.600 0.640 0.680 0.720 0.776 0.832 0.888
 [85] 0.944 1.000 1.056 1.112 1.168 1.224 1.280 1.352 1.424 1.496 1.568 1.640
 [97] 1.712 1.784 1.856 1.928 2.000
```

---

## Previous Answer

You can try `interp2` from package `pracma`, which is almost a mirror of MATLAB function `interp2` and can help you with 2-D interpolations (the major difference lies in the method options, since the MATLAB version contains 'linear', 'nearest', 'cubic', 'makima', or 'spline').

> - Description: Two-dimensional data interpolation similar to a table
>   look-up.
> - Usage:
>   `interp2(x, y, Z, xp, yp, method = c("linear", "nearest", "constant"))` Arguments `x`, `y`     vectors with monotonically increasing
>   elements, representing `x-` and `y-`coordinates of the data values in `Z`.
> - `Z`:     numeric `length(y)`-by-`length(x)` matrix.
> - `xp`, `yp`:  `x`-, `y`-coordinates of points at which interpolated values will
>   be computed.
> - `method`:    interpolation method, “linear” the most useful.

I think the default "linear" method is the one for the desired "2-D `approxfun`".

---

Below is an official example from `pracma::interp2`

```
library(pracma)
x <- linspace(-1, 1, 11)
y <- linspace(-1, 1, 11)
mgrid <- meshgrid(x, y)
Z <- mgrid$X^2 + mgrid$Y^2
xp <- yp <- linspace(-1, 1, 101)

method <- "linear"
zp <- interp2(x, y, Z, xp, yp, method)
plot(xp, zp, type = "l", col = "blue")

method <- "nearest"
zp <- interp2(x, y, Z, xp, yp, method)
lines(xp, zp, col = "red")
grid()
```

Comment: It's not exactly ideal, as it doesn't return a function, but it can be made to work.

Comment: @LBogaardt See my update.

Comment: This package also requires a matrix Z input, which is an unnecessary constraint.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers (so far) are ideal, nor is mine. However, this comes closest to what I personally was looking for. I hope this is helpful to the OP.

```
library(interp)
approxfun2 <- function(x1, x2, y) {
    function(xo1, xo2) {
        interp(x = x1, y = x2, z = y, xo = xo1, yo = xo2, output = "points")$z
    }
}

x1 <- c(rep(0, 10), rep(1, 10))
x2 <- rep(seq(10), 2)
y <- c(1 + 2 * seq(10), -0.1 * seq(10) ^ 2)
f <- approxfun2(x1, x2, y)
f(x1, x2) # returns y
f(c(rep(0, 19), rep(1, 19)), rep(seq(1, 10, 0.5), 2)) # returns y with intermediate values
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and very fast routine is `approxfun2` from the `cooltools` package available on CRAN. It generates a vectorised function analogous `approxfun`, which is much faster than most other 2D interpolators.

```
library(cooltools)
x = seq(3)
y = seq(4)
z = array(c(x+1,x+2,x+3,x+4),c(3,4))
f = approxfun2(x,y,z)
print(f(1.7,2.4))
```