# How to apply bilinear interpolation in R

Tags: interpolation, approximation

I have 2D data, and want to find the interpolant that approximates the function in R. In other words, I need to apply the general function of "approxfun()", but can't find the appropriate package/function.

Comment: What is the language/framework you use?

Comment: @Pavel As I mentioned, I use R. I know how to solve this problem for univariate function (it's the function "approxfun"), but don't know appropriate function for multivariate case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847639/seeking-2d-version-of-approxfun